# How do I browse directories for json files (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, json, file, directory

I want to browse directories for json files and merge all json files into one json file per directory.
My javascript skill is at beginner level.

The javascript code needs to run by calling it in the Terminal, not in the browser.

Comment: You can do this server-side (ie looking at server folders), but browser security won't allow you to do this on client machines.

Comment: No, it's not meant to run in a browser. The javascript code needs to run by calling it in the Terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of glob npm package to retrieve all json file paths in the directories.

glob : https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

you can simply go with :

```
const glob = require("glob");
const fs = require('fs-extra');

async function processJsonData(){
  let parentDirectoryPath = '<specify path here>';
  let data = {};

  let jsonFilePaths = glob.sync(`${parentDirectoryPath}/*/*.json`);
  //this will return paths for all the json files 

    for (const jsonFilePath of jsonFilePaths) {
        let content = await fs.readJsonSync(jsonFilePath);
        Object.assign(data,content);
    }

     await fs.writeJson(<filePath>, data, {spaces: 2});
    //here specify your file path
}
```

ps. I am a new contributor, might have misread the question.

Comment: I tested it and this works, I had to create the directory first before calling fs.writeJson

Thank you so much